# Removing NA from a variable in R

Tags: r

I want to know if I can remove NAs from a variable without creating a new subset?

The only solutions I find are making me create a new dataset. But I want to delete those rows that have NA in that variable right from the original dataset.

From:

Title   Length

1-   A        NA

2-   B        2

3-   C        7

Title   Length

2-   B        2

3-  C        7

Is it even possible?

The best solution I found was this one (but as I sad it creates a new dataset):
`completerecords <- na.omit(data$emp_length)`

Thank you,

Dani

Comment: `data = data[complete.cases(data),]`

Comment: Provide `dput(x)` of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse the same dataset name to overwrite the original one:

In your example, it would be:

```
data <- data[!is.na(data$emp_length),]
```

Note that this way you would remove only the rows that have NA in the column you're interested in, as requested. If some other rows have NA values in different columns, these rows will not be affected.